# Equivalence of definitions of regular cardinals

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I have seen two definitions for regular cardinals:

1. A cardinal $\kappa>\omega$ is regular iff $\mathrm{cof}(\kappa)=\kappa$; that is, the cofinality of $\kappa$ is $\kappa$.
2. For every map $f:\kappa\to\kappa$, there exists an ordinal $0<\alpha<\kappa$ that is closed under $f$; that is, $\forall \beta<\alpha(f(\beta)<\alpha)$.

I tried to prove that they are equivalent, but no luck. A cursory search on Google didn't turn up anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, these are equivalent. The first property *is* the standard definition.

If $\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)=\kappa>\omega$, and $f\colon\kappa\to\kappa$, fix any $\alpha_0<\kappa$, and define by recursion, $\alpha_{n+1}=\sup\{f(\alpha)\mid\alpha\leq\alpha_n\}$. By regularity, $\alpha_{n+1}<\kappa$, and so $\alpha=\sup\alpha_n<\kappa$ as well.

In the other direction, if $\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)=\mu<\kappa$, consider a function $f\colon\mu\kappa$ which is cofinal and $f(0)=\mu$, and extend it by setting $f(\alpha)=0$ for all $\alpha\geq\mu$. It is easy to see that if $\alpha<\mu$, then $\alpha$ is not closed under $f$, since $f(0)>\alpha$; and on the other hand, if $\alpha\geq\mu$ then $\sup\{f(\beta)\mid\beta<\alpha\}=\kappa>\alpha$.

Comment: I've never seen that definition before, so thank you! (Note that if we require that $f$ is non-decreasing in (2), then we only characterise $\operatorname{cf}(\kappa)>\omega$, so it is very important to allow functions that are not at all order preserving here!)